# PHP : Sandbox embedded signature not showing if signer 1 data email is different from DocuSign Sandbox Account email : normal?

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm embedding a signature via the Docusign API sandbox, using PHP. All works properly in my tests using the same email for signer 1 as my Docusign sandbox account. However, when i change that email to a dynamic one, the signature never shows up. Is this normal? Will this change once I move to a live (paid) account ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for generating the "embedded signing" view is probably hardcoding your email address and/or the clientUserId. They has to be the same email and clientUserId for the actual signer.
So, you need to know who the signer is not only when setting up the envelope, but also when making the second API call to generate a recipient view.

Comment: afraid not, i'm actually using the same object as the one used to create the signer, only adding the user_name property (same as the name property), authentication_method (None) and return_url. I forgot to add I'm using JWT to connect.

Comment: fixed! it was actually a problem with client_user_id not being the same in both calls. So you're answer actually lead me in the right track. Thanks so much!

Comment: yup, that would do it. I'll amend the answer to include this option so others who might run into this would know.